Limiting the upload in terms of volume or number of files in the TYPO3 backend
Is it possible to limit the uploads (in terms of volume or number)? Not for a single field but generally for uploads (for all upload fields and in the file list)?
Nowadays, high bandwidths are also possible upstream, so an editor could easily upload large quantities of (rather big) images, bringing the webserver to its knees during processing (extracting metadata, generating thumbnails, etc.).

Personally I'd say - uploads are related to identified editors and should be part of a training. Editors could also add thousands of pages and do other things that should be part of a chief editor regulating their editors. Having said that - I think with the file upload PSR events you could create some kind of rate limiting / statistics, and deny further uploads...?

You can configure the maximum file size in php.ini:
upload_max_filesize

The maximum size of an uploaded file.
max_file_uploads

The maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded simultaneously. Upload fields left blank on submission do not count towards this limit.
Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads
Recommendation from TYPO3
The following settings control the maximum upload file size (and should be adapted if necessary):
php.ini
; To allow uploads of a maximum of 10 MB
post_max_size = 10M
upload_max_filesize = 10M

Documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/SystemRequirements/Index.html

Do you know whether TYPO3 uses any "magic" (Ajax or similar) to optimize this? Because despite post_max_size = 30M, upload_max_filesize = 30M, max_file_uploads=20, an editor uploaded 70 files with a total of around 350 MB within 17s.... (Web server is located on the local LAN)
